# Javascript - need to repeat functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's first time I'm using stackoverflow :)
I have created an interaction using javascript for playing video with timer. The interaction is... the video will be paused by default and after 3 seconds that will start playing. This same thing I have to repeat three times. Can we do that? I have shared my code here.

```
var timeLeft = 3;
var elem = document.querySelector('.countdown-content__count');
var timerId;

function countdown() {
  if (timeLeft == 0) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeOut();
    $(".video-wrapper span").fadeOut();
    var playPromise = $("#video")[0].play();
    console.log(playPromise); 
  } else {
    elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    timeLeft--;
  }
}

function practiceShot(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".countdown-content__head").slideUp(1000,               function(){
          $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
              opacity: 0,
              display: 'inline-block'     
          }).animate({opacity:1},600);
          timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
          countdown();
        });
      }, 2000);
}
practiceShot();
```

jfiddle link for more clarification : [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/Coder95/ku6nw8r2/2/)

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: what does your code do, what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Oh, sorry mplungjan and Jaromanda X.. I forgot to share my link here. I have shared my link. https://jsfiddle.net/Coder95/ku6nw8r2/2/. And there is no problem there. I want to repeat what I did but don't know hoe to do that. Just started learning..

Comment: I'm sharing one more link also http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/counter-video/. Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: You need to change the fiddle to use jQuery like this https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/acjgfhkt/ - and what is happening or not happening that you want to happen?

Comment: the last link you shared is working exactly that. what do you mean by repeat? do you mean this video should play for more three seconds again stopped and again play for 3 seconds? something like this?

Comment: Hey pathak tejpal, based on the last link I shared ( dev.netbramha.in/projects/counter-video ) the video was paused and was playing after we showing the countdown. And again the video have to pause and have to show countdown to start playing video. Like this we need to repeat for three times.

Comment: Hey pathak tejpal, do have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this - I have applied the `addEventListener` on video `ended` event and use `videoCounter` variable to run the video only 3 times. It is initialized as `2` and gets decremented when the video end.

```js
var timeLeft = 3;
var videoCounter = 2;
var videoText = 2;
var elem = document.querySelector('.countdown-content__count');
var timerId;

function countdown() {
  if (timeLeft == 0) {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeOut();
    $(".video-wrapper span").fadeOut();
    var playPromise = $("#video")[0].play();
  } else {
    elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    timeLeft--;
  }
}

function practiceShot(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".countdown-content__head").slideUp(1000, function(){
          $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
              opacity: 0,
              display: 'inline-block'     
          }).animate({opacity:1},600);
          timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
          countdown();
        });
      }, 2000);
}
practiceShot();
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('ended', function() {
    if (videoCounter == 0) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("countdown-content__head")[0].innerHTML = "Practice Shot " + videoText;
    videoText++;
    videoCounter--;
    timeLeft = 3;
    elem.innerHTML = "";
    $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeIn();
    $(".video-wrapper span").fadeIn();
    $(".countdown-content__head").slideDown(1000, function(){
          $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
              opacity:1,
              display: 'inline-block'     
          }).animate({opacity:0},600);
    });
    practiceShot();
}, false);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One");
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
}

.main-content {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.video-wrapper span {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #FBED20;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.video-wrapper > video {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.countdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.countdown-content__head {
  margin: 0;
}

.countdown-content__timer {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}


.countdown-content__timer > span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">
  <span class="video-wrapper">
    <video id="video" muted>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
    <span></span>
  </span>
  <div class="countdown-content">
    <h1 class="countdown-content__head">Practice Shot 1</h1>
    <div class="countdown-content__timer">
      <span class="countdown-content__count"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: @mplungjan i have applied the `addEventListener ` on video end. You may find the code at the end in JS.

Comment: So thanks Sami Ahmed Siddiqui and mplungjan. And one more thing is the video is repeating many times. Can we do that only for three times?

Comment: @vaishnav I have updated the code. Please check now. I am initializing `videoCounter` to `2` and decrementing its value when video ended. so when it becomes `0` video will not repeat itself.

Comment: Yes Sami Ahmed Siddiqui, I got that it's working fine :)

Comment: Thanks for the all support from you guys :)

Comment: Hey guys one more question I have. can you please reply if you are ther?

Comment: @vaishnav What's the question?

Comment: Yeah Sami, help only if you have time. Can we change text on each video repatations? Like, "Practice shot 1" for first video play, "Practice shot 2" for srcond video play and finally "Practice shot 3" for third video play?

Comment: @vaishnav Answer updated. I have added `document.getElementsByClassName("countdown-content__head")[0].innerHTML = "Practice Shot " + videoCounter; ` line in the previous code. You can check the location of this line in the answer.

Comment: Let me check Sami.

Comment: Hey Sami, this is the thing. But in the third video repeatation its again showing "practice shot 1"..:(

Comment: @vaishnav Fixed. Please recheck

Comment: @everybody. This is the answer I was looking for and I got that from 'Sami Ahmed Siddiqui'.

Comment: Hey Sami, why that border of timer showing in wrong time? Its working good but one minor issue is only the border showing just before the text showing. I re-arranged the opacity thing many time, edited css. But a style "opacity:1" is showing in html as inline. I couldn't remove that. You have any idea?  I have updated the link with images and style : http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/timer/practice-shots.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `setTimeout()` in `practiceShot()` you should call `practiceShot()` in `setInterval` like this

```
 setInterval(function(){ practiceShot(); }, 2000);
```

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
The setInterval() method **will continue calling the function** until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

for details: [setInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Hey Afaq Ahmed Khan, let me try this

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setInterval()`, `clearInterval()` and a simple counter to repeat something as specific amount of times.

example:

```
var counter = 0;
var interval_id = setInterval(() => {
  play_video();
  counter++;
  if (counter >= 3) {
    clearInterval(interval_id)
  }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Hey delashum, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Use onended event handler on video element,

```
var timeLeft = 3;
var elem = document.querySelector('.countdown-content__count');
var timerId;
var times = 0 ;
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
vid.onended = function() {
    times++;
    console.log(times);
    times==3 ? $("#video")[0].pause() : $("#video")[0].play();;
};

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == 0) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        $(".countdown-content__timer").fadeOut();
        $(".video-wrapper span").fadeOut();
        var playPromise = $("#video")[0].play();
        console.log(playPromise);
    } else {
        elem.innerHTML = timeLeft;
        timeLeft--;
    }
}

function practiceShot() {
    $(".countdown-content__head").slideUp(1000, function () {
        $(".countdown-content__timer").css({
            opacity: 0,
            display: 'inline-block'
        }).animate({opacity: 1}, 600);
        timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
        countdown();
    });
}
practiceShot();
```